# How do you analyze the runtime complexity of a recursive function with both exponential and logarithmic properties?

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity

I'm not sure how the two recursive calls and the floor division of the following function interact regarding time complexity and big o notation.

```
def recurse(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    if n <= 0 or k <= 0:
        return 1
    return recurse(n//2, k) + recurse(n, k//2)
```

I see how O(2^(nk)) could serve as an upper bound because the k portion of (n//2,k) and the n portion of (n,k//2) dominate the growth rates. However I could also see something along the lines of (nlog(n)*mlog(m)) working as well and I'm not sure what to settle on.

Edit:
[image: Recursive call tree of n = 2 and k = 4]

Comment: Interesting puzzle.  I was able to find a closed-form non-recursive expression that gives the same result as `recurse` (which is the number of leaf calls to the function), but it's a little tricky.

Comment: I finally got around to writing up the exact solution.  See my posted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an exact solution.

The first thing to note is that, ignoring cases where n < 0
or k < 0, we only care about how many times we need to divide n or k
by two (using floor division) before they reach zero.  For example, if
n = 7, then we have 7, 3, 1, 0, which is three divisions by two.

The number of times a non-negative integer v can be divided by two
(using floor division) before reaching zero is ceil(log2(v+1)).

Let a = ceil(log2(n+1)) and b = ceil(log2(k+1)).  Then each recursive
call reduces either a or b by one, and continues until either a or b
reaches zero.

Now consider the call tree.  This is a binary tree, but not a balanced
tree (since some paths are longer than others).  A call is a leaf call
if either n or k is zero.  Further, each leaf call corresponds to a
single unique path through the call tree.  Each recursive call reduces
either a or b by one, so each leaf call corresponds to a unique
monotonic path from (a, b) to either (0, x) or (x, 0), since the
recursive calls end when either a or b becomes zero.  We can model
this by extending each path to (0, 0).  Then we just need to count
the number of paths from (a, b) to (0, 0).  This is just (a+b)!/(a!*b!).

This is a well-known result that isn't difficult to derive.  It can be
expressed as a multicombination (i.e., a combination in which multiple
instances of a given value are allowed).

So the number of leaf calls is (a+b)!/(a!*b!).  The number of
non-leaf calls is one less than this.  So we have:

1. leaf calls:         (a+b)!/(a!*b!)
2. non-leaf calls:     (a+b)!/(a!*b!) - 1
3. total calls:        2*(a+b)!/(a!*b!) - 1

The exact time complexity of `recurse` is O((a+b)!/(a!*b!)), where a = ceil(log2(n+1)) and b = ceil(log2(k+1)).

The return value of `recurse` is the number of leaf calls.  The function
`complexity` below behaves identically:

```
from math import factorial

def complexity(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    if n <= 0 or k <= 0:
        return 1

    a = ceil_log2(n+1)
    b = ceil_log2(k+1)

    return factorial(a + b) // (factorial(a) * factorial(b))
```

where `ceil_log2` is defined as:

```
def ceil_log2(x: int) -> int:
    if x <= 0:
        raise ValueError("log2 of zero or negative integer")

    return (x - 1).bit_length()
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I tried to build the call tree for n = 2 and k = 4 and added it as an edit. It seems like the formula you suggested accurately bounds the number of leaves but not the number of calls. Am I misinterpreting how the function works? Thanks!

Comment: (a+b)!/(a!*b!), also commonly known as "a+b choose a" or (a+b)Ca, and you can use `math.comb` :-). And if we count *different* calls at each level, we have [1] at the top level, [1,1] at the next level, [1,2,1] at the next level (since arguments (n/2,k/2) appear twice), [1,3,3,1] at the next, etc. Pascal's triangle. Or rather Pascal's *rectangle*, since we ***don't*** actually go down to (0,0) but stop when *one* of the args is zero. So I don't see why you're saying you got "the exact time complexity of recurse". You got the exact time complexity of that ...

Comment: ... modified version instead. Which is much simpler. I got that far last night, but didn't see a good way to compute the sum of Pascal's rectangle, so settled for my answer's overestimation.

Comment: Hmm. I tested and it does seem to be exact for the original recurse. What am I missing?

Comment: Ohh... I see. It's because you're focusing on the leaves, and appending a simple path from (0,>0) down to (0,0) adds more calls but doesn't change the number of leaves. So you get the correct number of leaves for both the original recurse and the modified recurse. And "one less non-leaf calls" is wrong for the modified recurse but correct for the original one. It's all good now. I'd just recommend to make your complexity return the total number of calls, not just leaves, and to use math.comb.

Comment: @KellyBundy I wondered about `math.comb` but didn't see it.  Apparently it was added in 3.8, while I'm running an older version.  But yeah, (a+b choose a), (a+b choose b), and (a+b)!/(a!\*b!) are all the same.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, extending the paths from (0,x) or (x,0) down to (0,0) doesn't change the total number of paths.  It just makes it easier to count them.  Then, once you have the number of leaf paths, the number of non-leaf paths is simply one less than that.

Comment: @KS520 I gave exact counts for the leaf calls, the non-leaf calls, and the total calls.  In this case, the time complexity of all three is considered equivalent, since for O values you can ignore constant scale factors and additions.  If there are L leaf calls, then there are L-1 non-leaf calls and 2\*L-1 total calls.  All three are O(L).

Comment: Still below 3.8? For shame! You're missing out on some useful stuff.

Comment: @KellyBundy Hah, yeah, I should upgrade at some point.  I don't have the walrus operator either.

Comment: @KS520 In the example tree that you added, the number of leaf calls L is 10, the number of non-leaf calls is L-1 = 9, and the total number of calls is 2*L-1 = 19.  If you count them you'll see they match.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks again. I understand it better after reading your comments and rereading your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Each call itself only does constant work, so overall time is proportional to the number of calls.

Let N and K be the arguments to the top call. Recursive calls keep one argument and halve the other. The first argument can get halved at most log2(N) times and the second argument at most log2(K) times. So you can't recurse deeper than log2(N)+log2(K) times. Thus we have at most 2<sup>log2(N)+log2(K)+1</sup>-1 = 2•2<sup>log2(NK)</sup>-1 = 2NK-1 calls. So complexity is O(NK).

Some testing suggests it's even less, i.e., O(NK) isn't tight. For N=K, it looks like O(NK / sqrt(log2(NK))).

Comment: Hi Kelly, I tried to build the call tree for n = 2 and k = 4 and added it as an edit. It seems like the number of recursive calls is more than the upper bound of NK = 8. Am I misinterpreting how the function works? Thanks!

Comment: Well, first: I wrote 2NK-1, not NK. So that's 17. You found 19. That's because I was a bit sloppy because I knew it doesn't matter for the complexity class. The log2 values need to get +1 since you recurse down to 0, not 1. But that only increases the maximum depth by 2. Which means ~4 times as many calls. And since big-O disregards constant factors, it's still O(NK). I might try to phrase it better after breakfast. It's always a struggle between being exact and being easy to read.

Comment: Ah sorry it makes sense now after going over it again. Thank you!